# how to refresh JSESSIONID cookie after login

Tags: tomcat, authentication, session-cookies, jsessionid

A product I work on got a tough security audit by a potential customer and they are upset that Tomcat sets a JSESSIONID cookie before authentication has happened.  That is, Tomcat sets this cookie when our stateless Login Page loads, but before login.

They suggest either of the following:

1. issue a new JSESSIONID cookie after login
2. prevent a JSESSIONID cookie from being set in the first place on the Login Page (i.e., before authentication has happened)

I have been poring through everything JSESSIONID-related on this site and can find no easy answer.  I'm just hoping for some ideas.  My best solutions for each are:

1. right after login, clone the Session (minus the id) by copying all the attributes, invalidating the old session, creating a new one, copying the values, associating it with the request, and hoping that works.
2. create a servlet Filter at the very end of the chain that strips out the JSESSIONID cookie before the Login Page is initially loaded.  And then hope the login request works out without a JSESSIONID set.

I've got to get some sleep, but will be attempting these in the morning.  It would be awesome to get some feedback or better suggestions from people much smarter than myself -- like you!

Regardless, I'll post my results here because it seems like a lot of other people have been wanting to do something similar.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You will not refresh after but just before. When executing the login action first do:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session!=null && !session.isNew()) {
    session.invalidate();
}
```

Then do:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); // create the session
// do the login (store the user in the session, or whatever)
```

FYI what you are solving with this trick is http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation

Lastly you can disable automatic session creation and only create the session when you really need it. If you use JSP you do that by:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"
        session="false"%>
```

Comment: Interesting stuff.  I'm using Wicket 1.3, and I can't seem to find a way to set 'session=false' (the view side is not JSP-based).  I'm going to try the getSession(false) idea now...  thanks!

Comment: Invalidating the session before login is causing Wicket chaos (just keeps redirecting to the Login Page).  Still messing with this...

Comment: @RichardsonHeights: Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1767 . It seems documented and solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to back port that Wicket fix to the older version of Wicket we're running, and it basically solved the problem.  It's opened some other problems in our legacy custom authentication scheme, but this should work for anyone using Wicket in general.

Comment: @cherouvim i can't thank you enough for that, i spent hours debugging.. i had another owasp link, which confused me because it says "Session ID should be regenerated after login" :https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Fixation_in_Java.. thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

I can't comment on @cherouvim's answer above as I don't have enough points. The new session ID should be set "after" the user successfully logs in, to avoid session fixation. I'll try and explain my reasoning.

Session fixation effectively means that an attacker somehow tricked a user into using a value known to the attacker. For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the attacker walked over to the user's desk, used Firebug and edited the user's cookie. Now when the user logs in, he/she will be logged in with the attacker controlled cookie. Since the attacker also knows this value he/she will refresh their browser and the resources mapped to that session ID (the victim's resources) will be served to them. That's session fixation. Correct?

Now let's say we ran a **session.invalidate** before the victim user logged in. Lets say the cookie initially had a value abc. On running **session.invalidate** the value abc is purged from the server's session.

Now comes the part where I disagree. What you suggest is to generate a new session before the user actually logs in (Enters username and password and clicks submit). This will no doubt cause a new cookie to get generated but it will be on the user's browser before they login. So if an attacker can edit the "prelogin" cookie again, the attack still persists, as the same cookie will be used even after the user logs in.

I think this is the correct flow.

- User does a GET /login.html
- Return Login page with whatever cookie is currently there in the browser
- User enters credentials and clicks submit
- Application verifies credentials
- On finding that credentials were correct. the session.invalidate() is run ..destroying the old cookie.
- NOW generate the new cookie using **request.getSession(true)**

What this means, is that even if an attacker manages to trick you into using a controlled value prior to logging in, you're still protected..as the application forcibly changes the value after you log in.

Here is a good blog about this issue - https://blog.whitehatsec.com/tag/session-fixation/

Answer (score 10):

`HttpServletRequest.changeSessionId()` can be use to change the session ID at any point of time.

Comment: This is the right answer with newer versions of Tomcat

Answer (score 5):

I have followed following way to regenerate the new session from old session. Hope you will be benefited from it.

```
private void regenerateSession(HttpServletRequest request) {

    HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession();

    Enumeration attrNames = oldSession.getAttributeNames();
    Properties props = new Properties();

    if (attrNames != null) {
        while (attrNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement();
            props.put(key, oldSession.getAttribute(key));
        }

        //Invalidating previous session
        oldSession.invalidate();
        //Generate new session
        HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
        attrNames = props.keys();

        while (attrNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement();
            newSession.setAttribute(key, props.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

When using spring, you should use `SessionFixationProtectionStrategy`.

```
<property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas"/>
...
<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"/>
```

When inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java), you will see that this is similar to the approach of harsha89: It will

1. create a new session
2. tranfer attributes of the old session.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I've found that might helpful to others.

1. If you're using Apache Wicket, there is a solution for this after version 1.4.  My app is still on 1.3, so I didn't realize, but I was able to back port it very easily in my own WebSession class. Wicket 1.4 adds a replaceSession() method to WebSession, which works great.  You can call it right after authentication and you'll get a new JSESSIONID.  It basically solved this problem for me.  More info here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1767.
2. There is a Apache Tomcat valve available after version 5.5.29 which you can add to context.xml. It will handle issuing a new JSESSIONID after authentication.  More info is available here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45255.  The entry for the valve would look like this: `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator" changeSessionIdOnAuthentication="true"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that the JSESSIONID is visible in the browser or that it gets set in a cookie at all? I'm assuming it is the latter in your case.

> 1.issue a new JSESSIONID cookie after login

This is the default Tomcat behaviour *if you switch from http to https* at the time of login. The old one is discarded and a new one is generated.

If your login itself is over http, I guess that's another security issue for the auditors ;)

Or are all your pages over https?

Comment: The problem is that the JSESSIONID cookie is set in the browser and visible in the Firefox cookie viewer (for example).  As cherouvim points out above, it's the "session fixation" security hole.

Interesting about the http/https switch... The app only runs over https, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat and want to apply this globally to all your servlets which use Tomcat's authentication mechanism, you can write a Valve to force this behavior, as shown in this [sample code.](http://www.koelnerwasser.de/?p=11)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the older version of jboss like jboss 4 then simply calling the request.getSession(true) after session.invalidate() call will not change the session id.

If you don't want to use valve and want to change the session id in action class same can be archived using reflection because CatalinaRequest will be not available directly in your action class.

Sample code

```
private HttpSession changeSessionId( HttpServletRequest request )
{
    HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession( false );
    HttpSession newSession = null;

    try
    {
        //get all cookies from request
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        //Get all attribute from old session
        Enumeration< Object > attrNames = oldSession.getAttributeNames();

        Properties attributFromOldSession = new Properties();

        while ( attrNames.hasMoreElements() )
        {
            String key = (String)attrNames.nextElement();
            attributFromOldSession.put( key, oldSession.getAttribute( key ) );
        }

        //Actual logic to change session id

        Field catalinaRequestField;

        //Getting actual catalina request using reflection
        catalinaRequestField = request.getClass().getDeclaredField( "request" );
        catalinaRequestField.setAccessible( true ); // grant access to (protected) field
        Request realRequest = (Request)catalinaRequestField.get( request );

        //Invalidating actual request
        realRequest.getSession( true ).invalidate();
        realRequest.setRequestedSessionId( null );
        realRequest.clearCookies();

        //setting new session Id
        realRequest.setRequestedSessionId( realRequest.getSessionInternal( true ).getId() );

        //Put back the cookies
        for ( Cookie cookie : cookies )
        {

            if ( !"JSESSIONID".equals( cookie.getName() ) )
            {
                realRequest.addCookie( cookie );
            }
        }

        // put attribute from old session
        attrNames = attributFromOldSession.keys();

        while ( attrNames.hasMoreElements() )
        {
            String key = (String)attrNames.nextElement();
            newSession.setAttribute( key, attributFromOldSession.get( key ) );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newSession;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
session=request.getSession(true);
Enumeration keys = session.getAttributeNames();     
HashMap<String,Object> hm=new HashMap<String,Object>();  
while (keys.hasMoreElements())
{
  String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
  hm.put(key,session.getValue(key));
  session.removeAttribute(key);      
}
session.invalidate();
session=request.getSession(true);
for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet())
{
  session.setAttribute((String)m.getKey(),m.getValue());  
  hm.remove(m);
}
```